# 3d Casimir effect

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, casimir-effect

Why do the virtual photons have to be in alignment with the normal of the plates in the [Casimir effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect)?

Are diagonal photons restricted to a different set of harmonics depending on their angle? And if not, why not?

Comment: What derivation did you read? Requiring the virtual photons to be normal to the plates is not part of the usual derivation. The photons are characterized by, say, $k_x$, $k_y$, and $n_z$. The first two are continuous; the third is integral. But the photon can propagate diagonally with such momentum.

Comment: one should emphasize the **virtual** . The  virtual photons are mathematical constructs to model the effect.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html second page.

Comment: @Ghoster if the first two are continuous, dosent this mean that any frequency is allowed as long as it has a an x or y component?

Comment: Yes, that seems right.